# Can't create push notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with push notification in Android Studio.
I send to my device the notification from the firebase web console. I receive the notification because i see the body in the logcat, but i can't create the push notification.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
}

String TAG = "";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null) {
        Log.e("FIREBASE", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }
}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id_0")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

}

My user-permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

My service declaration:

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <!--android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"-->

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

[notification text is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpes6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using device with >= Oreo? Use code below. With pendingIntent you can open your activity by touching the notification (Remove if you don't need it):

```
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String messageTitle) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = "channel_id_0";
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .setContentTitle(messageTitle))
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```